# How can I select the same children across different parents?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have this HTML code

```html
  <select  id="from">
    child  
      child
        child 
          <div class="dropdownDiv">
            <ul>
              <li class=""><a href="#"  text="John" value="Jo"> John </a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Mary" value="Ma"> Mary </a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Kevin" value="Ke"> Kevin </a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Sandra" value="Sa"> Sandra </a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Claire" value="Cl"> Claire </a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </select>


   <select  id="to">
      child  
        child
          child 
            <div class="dropdownDiv">
              <ul>
                <li class=""><a href="#"  text="John" value="Jo"> John </a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Mary" value="Ma"> Mary </a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Kevin" value="Ke"> Kevin </a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Sandra" value="Sa"> Sandra </a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#"  text="Claire" value="Cl"> Claire </a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </select>
```

Using CSS_Selector in Java Selenium,

1. how can I click Sandra from parent `id="from"` and
2. how can I click Sandra from parent `id="to"` ?

Using **Xpath**, I could simply say

1. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='Sa'])[1]")).click();`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='Sa'])[2]")).click()`

How can I do the same thing using CSS selectors?

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<select>`. `<option>` and `<optgroup>` are valid children of `<select>` only.

Comment: try `select a[value="Sa"]` as the selector - i.e. something along the lines of `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(select a[value='Sa'])[1]).click();`

Comment: Thanks @ochi .  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("(a[value='Sa'])[2]")).click();` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @keylogger you are missing the select in the selector but it should be close to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML needs to be corrected because `div` and `ul` aren't valid children of `<select>`. The valid children of `<select>` are `<option>` and `<optgroup>`.

```
<select  id="from">
    <option value="Jo">John</option>
    <option value="Ma">Mary</option>
    <option value="Ke">Kevin</option>
    <option value="Sa">Sandra</option>
    <option value="Cl">Claire</option>
</select>

<select  id="to">
    <option value="Jo">John</option>
    <option value="Ma">Mary</option>
    <option value="Ke">Kevin</option>
    <option value="Sa">Sandra</option>
    <option value="Cl">Claire</option>
</select>
```

**Selenium**

I recommend that you take a look at the Java [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) for Selenium.

With the corrected HTML, you are able to use `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector here"))` to solve your problem. The documentation for that is [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/).

Here's an example for clicking Sandra with parent `id="from"`.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#from")).click(); // to show the drop down
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#from option[value=Sa]")).click();
```

You can modify the code above to work for the parent `id="to"` as well.